# Disabling Firebase Analytics and App performance

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

To better understand how our users are using our suite of apps we have decided to use Firebase Analytics in our apps to collect user behaviour data. We also wanted to determine how our apps were performing so we decided to include Firebase Performance monitoring in our applications.

To manage to toggle on and off of data collection, we decide to user LaunchDarkly:   https://launchdarkly.com/ for feature management. To enable and disable the collection of data in an application the following lines of code need to be run.

I set the value of firebase_analytics_collection_enabled to false, by default in the app, with the following metadata in the application tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

and to re-enable data collection i use the following line of code:

```
setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
```

and to disable data collection:

```
setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
```

The main concern for following this approach was to conserve data usage because if the analytics are switched on they constantly transmit the collected data and this leads to increased data usage.

However, I don't believe this stops the app performance data collection as the firebase app performance SDK does not seem to use google play services to transmit the data.

How would I be able to enable and disable the app performance analysis from the Firebase when I need to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable/disable collection of performance monitoring data from within your application code with:

```
FirebasePerformance.getInstance().setPerformanceCollectionEnabled(false);
```

Also see:

- the Firebase guide on [disabling performance monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/disable-sdk?platform=android#disable-with-remote-config)
- the [reference documenation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/perf/FirebasePerformance.html#setPerformanceCollectionEnabled(boolean))